# How to skip several iterations of a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, skip

Is there a clean way to skip several iterations from a from a `for` loop?

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i< count; i++)
{
   if (condition)
   {
       // skip several iterations of "i"
       continue(5);
   }
}
```

Comment: if(i>2 && i<5) ?? it wil work i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following

```
i+= 5;
continue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value of `i`, that will skip some iterations:

```
for (int i = 0; i< count; i++)
{
   if (condition)
   {
       i+=5;
       continue;
   }
}
```